# Unable to print PHP variable using JS

Tags: javascript, php

I understand that this question has been asked a lot of of times, but the solutions posted there don't seem to work for me. I have a code as follows:

```
<script>
  var JSvar = "<?php echo $phpVar ?>";
  document.write(JSvar);
</script>
<?php 
$phpVar="jajha";
?>
```

I actually want to pass a PHP variable to a JS function, but I wanted to try if printing the variable works first. Please help me out.

Comment: it won't work if you don't define it first (you should get an error for that, too)

Comment: PHP and Javascript cannot time travel... And even if this was working, DON'T spit php output directly into a JS context. use `json_encode()` to guaranteed you're outputting syntactically correct JS.

Comment: [Please, don't use `document.write()`!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
<script>
  var JSvar = "<?php echo $phpVar ?>";
  document.write(JSvar);
</script>
<?php 
$phpVar="jajha";
?>
```

try

```
<?php 
    $phpVar="jajha";
    ?>
<script>
    var JSvar = "<?php echo $phpVar ?>";
    document.write(JSvar);
</script>
```

Comment: You're assuming that the OP has not set the PHP variable.

Comment: @jrath it worked. Thanks a lot. But is there a way by which I can do that calling a function?